# Tag proposal for formalistic/bureaucratic/legaleze: officialese?

Tags: discussion, tags

When encountering [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31326/1696) I searched for a tag to mark words, which are never spoken by a living person, but live only in official documents. It would a a kind of counterpart to *colloquial*.

Further illustrative examples are:

- Typprüfungsbescheinigung
- Fernsprechverzeichnis

Pro: Since these words are frequently compounds of two or more substantives, a learner will likely fail to find them in dictionaries.

Contra: There may be too few questions to apply.

A German variant is *Amtsdeutsch*.

Any opinions?

Comment: Note that we already have [tag:legal-terminology].

Comment: Inventing a word for a tag might not be effective in helping learners find said category. Most English-speaking students will know about legalese

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Didn't invent, see [pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=officialese&l=deen&in=en&lf=en)

Comment: oh, ok. Google ngram says, its usage is declining in favor of legalese: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=officialese%2C+legalese&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cofficialese%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bofficialese%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOfficialese%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOFFICIALESE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clegalese%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blegalese%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegalese%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLEGALESE%3B%2Cc0